# Charles Proxy showing "unknown" with android device

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I beleive I have installed charles poxy certificate correctly on my android device, and the android device is set to proxy to the ip shown in charles proxy local ip

In the structure view "SSL Proxying is enabled for the host" is written when I click the host I am trying to analyize, however when that host is expanded the routes called below it are all showing as "unknown" Proxying is not enabled with the error
"SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown"

I think it only happens with android apps as well not browser searches etc

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think this may be becuase later android OS apps dont trust user certificates so I need to root and install as a base system certificate

Comment: See the failure message: `SSL handshake with client failed: When access control was applied the certificate was rejected (access_denied)` and the note: `You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.` As this only happens with one connection the reason may be that one performs TLS certificate pinning and thus does not accept the installed Charles root CA certificate.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, actually this same app works ok on ios, so I concluded it is because android OS doesnt allow user installed certs for apps, the others that were ok were websites not apps

Comment: On Android most apps ignore user installed certificates (Chrome does not ignore them), on iOS you can add user installed certs as trusted, that is a major difference.